# What's the Eclipse Andmore Project?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, andmore

**Android Studio** was announced in May 2013 and maintained by Android technology team since then. It is based on the **IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition**, added features that are designed specifically for Android development and cooperated with **JetBrains**, creators of one of the most advanced Java IDEs available today. As the official Android IDE, Android Studio gives us access to a powerful and comprehensive suite of tools to evolve our app across Android platforms, whether it's on the phone, wrist, car or TV.

As **Android Studio** arises, **Eclipse**, the powerful open-sourced IDE, worked with **Android Developer Tools (ADT)** to create gorgeous Android apps, begins to fall. Now that when **Android M Preview** was released, **Eclipse** couldn't work with the latest **Android SDK** whose structure was changed but **Eclipse** couldn't adapt it.

It is said that development and official support for the **ADT** in **Eclipse** will be ended at the end of the year, just to make way for focus on all of their efforts on making **Android Studio** better and faster. But **Eclipse** isn't abandoned completely for Android Development. Android tools inside it continues to live. They created a new project called **Andmore** - **Eclipse Android Tooling**.

So, what is **Andmore**? Now that **ADT in Eclipse** is not supported any more, they create this **Eclipse Android Tooling** for what? After **Eclipse** don't work for Android development at all, developers would switch to **Android Studio**, the official IDE, I think, will someone prefer **Andmore** in **Eclipse**? If so, what are advantages of **Andmore** in **Eclipse** which force them to choose it?

Any tips will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The purpose of **Andmore** is to provide **Android Eclipse tooling** without having to go through multiple steps.

The technology development involves integrating and refactoring the Google **ADT** plugins as necessary to work with the project. Similarly, the former **MOTODEV** plugins have components that can be integrated into the project.

**Andmore** includes:

- JDT for Android Java applications.
- CDT for C/C++ shared libraries.
- Gradle tooling (details TBD)
- Maven Build support via the M2E-Android Eclipse Plugin.
- Ant support via the built in Eclipse support for ANT.
- A fork of Google's ADT (Android Development Tools) plugins for
  Eclipse.These are maintained separately from Google's code line at AOSP, which will not be updated with any regularity.
- The former MOTODEV Studio Plugins (now part of the Android Open
  Source Project) upgraded to work with ADT.
- A p2 repository and product build using tycho.
- Mylyn Reviews for Gerrit Review integration.
- EGit for source code management.
- GitHub Plugin from EGit for better collaboration with GitHub
  projects.

In addition to components, **Andmore** will produce an **EPP** package.

The source code for **Andmore** is maintained on **Github**. To contribute, please make sure you have a signed **CLA** with the **Eclipse Foundation** on file, and fork the repository.  Pull requests and will be reviewed by an existing committer before being merged.

Source repository can be found at https://github.com/eclipse/andmore/