# Android Eclipse vs Android Studio 2016

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

On the previous year I choose the eclipse w/ android-sdk for android development, because it's better than Android Studio which is currently updating during that year 2015. Now that android studio has updated its components which is now best to use? Should I still stick to eclipse w/ android-sdk or should I change to Android Studio?

Comment: As of 2016, Eclipse is no longer officially supported as an Android development platform. Therefore, switch. You may even find that the JetBrains IDEs are better

Comment: Quoting from  [Official Developer Site](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) **Note: If you have been using Eclipse with ADT, be aware that Android Studio is now the official IDE for Android, so you should migrate to Android Studio to receive all the latest IDE updates. For help moving projects, see Migrating to Android Studio.**

Comment: Rumor has it that Android may be going to swift. Google and Oracle don't play friendly.

Comment: @Pomagranite It would be the end of Android.

Comment: http://thenextweb.com/dd/2016/04/07/google-facebook-uber-swift/

Comment: http://www.businessinsider.com/oracle-and-google-fail-to-settle-lawsuit-2016-4?op=1

Comment: For me this question and comments were very informative.

Comment: Why this question is being voted down? It is a fair question and I love to hear the community opinion on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the following links:

[ADT Plugin Release Notes](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html)

> Note: If you have been using Eclipse with ADT, be aware that Android Studio is now the official IDE for Android, so you should migrate to Android Studio to receive all the latest IDE updates. For help moving projects, see Migrating to Android Studio.

[Android Developer Tools](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adt.html)

> Important: Support for the Android Developer Tools (ADT) in Eclipse has ended, per our announcement. You should migrate your app development projects to Android Studio as soon as possible. For more information on transitioning to Android Studio, see Migrating from Eclipse ADT.

Also, I think this questions and answers will help you:

[Which Eclipse works flawlessly with ADT?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29991460/5721199)

[What's the Eclipse Andmore Project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31088451/whats-the-eclipse-andmore-project)

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the Andmore project has taken over the ADT development of Eclipse